# Error inserting rows to tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I need to dynamically update a tableview as the user scrolls. I am displaying data from a huge database, so for the sake of memory management, I used the following code to dynamically update the table as the user scrolls. What I did is that I updated the tableView by adding 30 rows to the end of the table when the tableView loads `indexPath.row == 30` and the user is scrolling down and remove 30 rows from the beginning. Similarly when `indexPath.row == 20` and the user is scrolling up, 30 rows are added to the beginning and 30 rows are beginning deleted from end. The following condition is written in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if ((indexPath.row == 30) && isDown) {
    [self addRowsToBeginningOfTable];
}
if ((indexPath.row == 20) && isUp) {
    [self addRowsToEndOfTable];
}
```

In this, isDown is true when the user is scrollingUp and isUp is true when the user is scrolling down(I know it is weird, but the isUp and isDown are the swipe directions from the user). The `addRowsToBeginningOfTable` and `addRowsToEndOfTable` are given below:

```
- (void)addRowsToEndOfTable {
    NSInteger rowCount = [arrayOfText count];
    int rowId = [[arrayOfText objectAtIndex:rowCount-1]intValue];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPathEnd = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i+rowCount inSection:0];
        NSIndexPath *indexPathBeginning = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [arrayOfText insertObject:@"New Object" atIndex:--rowId];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathEnd] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [arrayOfText removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathBeginning] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [tableView endUpdates]; //exception breakpoint hits here
    }
}

- (void)addRowsToBeginningOfTable {
    NSInteger rowCount = [arrayOfText count];
    int rowId = [[arrayOfText objectAtIndex:0]intValue];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPathEnd = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i+rowCount inSection:0];
        NSIndexPath *indexPathBeginning = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [arrayOfText addObjectAtIndex:i WithRowId:--rowId];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathBeginning] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [arrayOfText removeObjectAtIndex:i+rowCount];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathEnd] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

But when I scroll the tableView and `indexPath.row == 30` condition is satisfied, the app crashes showing the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:909
```

I set an exception breakpoint and saw that it hit the line where the comment is given in the above code. How can I rectify this? Or is this not the right way to update the table without the user knowing that the tableView is being updated as he is scrolling?

Comment: why don't you use Core Data and its amazing class `NSFetchedResultsController`? It can resolve all your issues

Comment: @ValentinShamardin: My database is at a remote location. Rather, it is an app update, I don't want the entire thing to be rebuilt. This is possible right??

Comment: So, you get objects for dataSource from internet, yes? And you have to store them to present in a tableView? You could insert objects to local Core Data storage dynamically. And update your tableView via NSFetchResultsController without any problems.